# Checking Frequency of Pulse, zero pulse case Android

Tags: android, frequency, ioio

I have a sensor that is measuring wind speed. For zero wind it outputs 0V (LOW) and has no pulse. However it outputs pulses (HIGH) for any speed greater then 0.3m/s. I am trying to write some code to intepret this in android, and have been using the getFrequency() function for pulse input which appears to be working fine, except for the zero pulse case.

I was just wondering what was the best way to deal with this? It seems I would need to check for a LOW and if x time passes before the next HIGH, write zero to wind speed?

can i have some sort of timer that breaks a waitForValue(true) ?

Thanks

Comment: I should also add I am using the ioio library

Answer (score 0):

Modify ioio.lib.impl.IncapImpl Class in IOIO Library

getFrequency
waitPulseGetDuration
-> waitPulseGetDuration(long waittime) ...Thread...sleep(waittime)

- I have removed the attributes: valid and queue
  valid blocks on start, queue works as first in first out and could deliver an old value